# Alerts not displaying in IE 11 using prod profile on JHipster 4.14.2

Tags: jhipster

We've just moved our first small JHipster app into production, very exciting and thank you once again for such an awesome project tool.

One small thing we have noticed though, on IE 11, (which is the only approved browser my client currently uses in the company), the alert messages no longer appear. Firefox and Chrome works perfect though.

Could this please be verified? I suspect an additional polyfill maybe needed.

I get no errors in IE developer tools console.

### Update:

Alerts work in IE11 using the dev profile but not in prod profile.

This is what is displayed in dev profile IE11.

[image: devprofile]

This is what is displayed in the prod profile IE11.

[image: This is what is displayed in prod profile IE11]

Comment: Not really a question for stackoverflow, I would rather close ths and ope, a github issue if you have been able to reproduce it on a very simple app.

Comment: JHipster alerts are mainly ngb-alert, have you tested it in IE11 on https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples

Comment: Thanks Gael, I'll definitely give that suggestion/test a try before I log an issue on the github page. If still no go, I'll move it across to the JHipster github page. Yes indeed, I have replicated it, my app is very simple, I've also regenerated a few entities to make sure I wasn't missing something. Thank you for the response. I'll first verify against your comments above.

Comment: The ngb-alert demo has  a plunkr  so it might help too

Comment: Just tested ie11 in plunkr, it works. So it might be a jhipster issue, have you tried to put a breakpoint in alert service?

Comment: I confirm it works in our IE 11 too. I will try debugging it next, will do thank you. I'll see what I can uncover. I get the feeling its not anything major.

Comment: Thank Gael for the responses, looks like its something to do with the way the app is packaged for the prod profile. In the dev profile all the notifications work quite fine in IE11. As soon as I package the app using the command `./mvnw -Pprod clean package`, the notifications disappear and the error alerts only display the error key. I'll move this one to the github page as requested.

Comment: Good investigation.